# Proof for subgroup of SL(2,q)

Tags: matrices, group-theory, finite-fields

In Suzuki's Group Theory I, Theorem 6.21 says

> Let $p$ be an odd prime number, and let $\lambda$ be an element of $F$ which is algebraic over the prime field $F_0=GF(p)$. Set $E=F_0(\lambda)$. Let $G$ be defined as follows: $$G=\left\langle\left(\begin{matrix}1&0\\1&1\end{matrix}\right),\quad\left(\begin{matrix}1&\lambda\\0&1\end{matrix}\right)\right\rangle$$ Then, either $G$ is isomorphic to $SL(2,E)$, or we have $p=3$, $\lambda^2=-1$, $E=GF(9)$, and $G\cong SL(2,5)$.

The first idea of the proof confuses me. It says

> The group $G$ is a subgroup of $SL(2,E)$ generated by two non-commutative elements of order $p$. So, by Theorem 6.17, either $G\cong SL(2,p^n)$, or $p=3$ and $G\cong SL(2,5)$.

In Theorem 6.17, another case for subgroups of $SL(V)$ is that $G$ is congruent to $\langle SL(2,p^n),d_\pi\rangle$, where $d_\pi=\left(\begin{matrix}\pi&0\\0&\pi^{-1}\end{matrix}\right)$. Why is this case not possible for our $G$?

Comment: I don't have the book to hand, and you have not said what $n$ or $d_\pi$ is, bu I would guess that for that other case to arise ${\rm GF}(p^n)$ would have to be a proper subfield of $E$, in which case the second generator of $G$ does not lie in that subgroup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This other group $\langle SL_2(p^n),d_\pi\rangle$ is not defined over $GF(p^n)$, as $\pi$ lies in $GF(p^{2n})$ and not in $GF(p^n)$. Thus $G$ cannot be this group.

Edit: as per the comments, this group is eliminated in the proof because it has a normal subgroup of index $2$. As such, it cannot be generated by two elements of order $p$, as all elements of order $p$ are contained in the normal subgroup.

Comment: $E$ is not $GF(p^n)$. So the proof really could say "either $G\cong SL(2,p^n)$ for SOME n.

e.g. Why can't $E$ be $\mathbb{F}_{25}$ and $G$ be $\langle SL(5),d_{\pi}\rangle$ for some $\pi=\sqrt{2}$

Comment: $E$ is $GF(p^n)$ for $n$ the degree of the minimal polynomial for $\lambda$.

Comment: Also, the group you are talking about has a normal subgroup of index $2$, so cannot be generated by two elements of order $p$.

Comment: ??? $G$ is by definition generated by two elements of order $p$.

Comment: It's unclear to me why $G$ could not be isomorphic to, say, $\langle SL(5),d_\pi\rangle$ as a subgroup of $SL(25)$.

Comment: Oh $\langle SL(2,p^n),d_\pi\rangle$ has the normal subgroup! Thank you!

Comment: The group $\mathrm{PGL}_2(q)$ embeds in the group $\mathrm{PSL}_2(q^2)$. This group is the preimage in $\mathrm{SL}_2(q^2)$.

Comment: Sorry, follow-up question. Why does the normal subgroup contain all the elements of order p?

Comment: Because it has $p'$-index. If $x\in G$ then $x^2$ lies in the normal subgroup. But if $x$ has odd order then $x$ lies in $\langle x^2\rangle$.